# how to use map in index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column on a pandas dataframe using values on the index and a dictionary that translates these values into something more meaningful. My initial idea was to use map. I arrived to a solution but it is very convoluted and there must be a more elegant way to do it. Suggestions?

```
#dataframe and dict definition
df=pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3],'boo':[3,4,5]},index=['a','b','c'])
d={'a':'aa','b':'bb','c':'cc'}

df['new column']=df.reset_index().set_index('index',drop=False)['index'].map(d)
```

Comment: Can you give some more information on your desired output?

Comment: Umm... `df['new column'] = df.index.to_series().map(d)` is one way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new series explicitly is a bit shorter:

```
df['new column'] = pd.Series(df.index, index=df.index).map(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

After `to_series`, you can using `map` or `replace`

```
df.index=df.index.to_series().map(d)
df
Out[806]: 
    boo  foo
aa    3    1
bb    4    2
cc    5    3
```

Or we think about another way

```
df['New']=pd.Series(d).get(df.index)
df
Out[818]: 
   boo  foo New
a    3    1  aa
b    4    2  bb
c    5    3  cc
```